# why f:ajax is not updating the value of a component if there are any validations in the form?

Tags: ajax, jsf

Hi i am doing simple registration page which contains common fields, i wanted to practice ajax in jsf using `f:ajax`. when there are no validations for any fields in the form the my `h:outputText` is getting updated normally. When i add validations to the fields the event is firing but it is not updating the `h:outputText` component.Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>JSF Tutorial!</title>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
    <!--    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="materialize.css"></h:outputStylesheet> -->
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="script.js"></h:outputScript>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p style="text-align: center">
        <!--        <h:graphicImage styleClass="table" -->
        <!--            value="http://vijayinfoart.com/wp-content/themes/theme46787/images/logo.png" /> -->
    </p>
    <h3 style="text-align: center">REGISTRATION FORM</h3>
    <h:form>

        <h:messages
            style="color:red;margin:8px;text-align:center;list-style-type:none;" />
        <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1"
            styleClass="table">

            <h:outputText value="User Name:" escape="false" />
            <h:inputText value="#{display.user}" required="true" label="User ID"
                id="userName">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="[A-Za-z]*[\.][A-Za-z]*"></f:validateRegex>
<!--                <f:validator validatorId="com.jason.jsf.custom.Myvalidator"></f:validator> -->

            </h:inputText>

            <h:outputText value="Email:" escape="false" />
            <h:inputText value="#{display.email}" required="true"
                label="Email ID"
                validatorMessage="#{display.email} is not valid email">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
                <f:ajax execute="userName" render="outputMessage" event="blur" />

            </h:inputText>

            <h:outputText value="Password" escape="false" />
            <h:inputSecret value="#{display.password}" id="password"
                required="true" label="Password">
                <f:validateLength for="password" minimum="6" maximum="10" />
                <f:validateRegex pattern="((?=.[0-9]+).{6,})"></f:validateRegex>

            </h:inputSecret>

            <h:outputText value="Address" escape="false" />
            <h:inputTextarea rows="3" cols="22" value="#{display.address}" />

            <h:outputText value="Programmer" escape="false" />
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkstatus" onclick="show()"
                value="#{display.status}" />

            <h:outputText value="Skills" escape="false" />
            <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{display.skills}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="java" itemLabel="JAVA" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="php" itemLabel="PHP" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="ruby" itemLabel="RUBY" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue=".net" itemLabel=".NET" />

            </h:selectManyCheckbox>

            <h:outputText value="Gender" escape="false" />
            <h:selectOneRadio value="#{display.gender}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Male" itemLabel="Male" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="female" itemLabel="Female" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>

            <h:outputText value="Work Mode" escape="false" />
            <h:selectOneListbox value="#{display.mode}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Parttime" itemLabel="Part Time" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="fulltime" itemLabel="Full Time" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="work from home" itemLabel="Work from Home" />
            </h:selectOneListbox>

            <h:outputText value="Database Skills" escape="false" />
            <h:selectManyListbox value="#{display.dblist}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="hibernate" itemLabel="HIBERNATE" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="jpa" itemLabel="JPA" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="oracle" itemLabel="ORACLE" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="mysql" itemLabel="MYSQL" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="MangoDB" itemLabel="MANGO DB" />
            </h:selectManyListbox>

            <h:outputText value="Certifications" escape="false" />
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{display.frameworks}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="SCJP"
                    itemLabel="Sun Certified Java Programmer" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="ocda"
                    itemLabel="Oracle Certified Database Administrator" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="ocdd"
                    itemLabel="Oracle Certified Database Developer" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:outputText value="Already a member?" escape="false" />
            <h:link value="Click Here!" outcome="page1" />

            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="display">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{display.application}"
                    value="Registration"></f:setPropertyActionListener>


            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value="cancel">
            <f:ajax execute="userName" render="outputMessage" />

            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h2></h2>
<h:outputText id="outputMessage"
            value="#{display.welcomeMessage !=null ?
            display.welcomeMessage : 'y'}" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

can somebody tell me the f:ajax behavior in jsf and how could i deal with both validations along with ajax in my page.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Means validation failed for one of the fields. Fix the validation error and you'll be fine

Comment: Got it fixed, the problem is with the validation so once the validation for a particular component is fine then only ajax will be triggered.